# not able import subgroup project's in other project

Tags: go, import

```
import path "https://gitlab.xxxxx.com/group/group/subgroup/project"
```

I am trying to import subgroup projects in other project , But its says fatal error on main group.

> "fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.******.com/group/group.git/' not found."

Comment: I _think_ this is unsolved problem with Gitlab where gitlab simply announces wrong metadata if queried about packages in soubgroups.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/30785